# Loop through all the inventory database and join three tables to one array

Tags: php, sql, pdo

i have an inventory of cars in splitted in three different tables with each car having the same `aut_id` on all three tables.

im trying to loop through the cars `while ($counter <= $autocount)` meaning for every car, and get info from the three tables for each car  to display the data like `mileage` and `price`

here is my code so far

```
while ($counter <= $autocount)  //ie run for every car 
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `auto` WHERE `auto_id` > $auto_id AND 
    `sold` = $soldvalue";
    $get = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $get->execute();

    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `attributes` WHERE `auto_id` > $auto_id AND 
    `sold` = $soldvalue";
    $get1 = $dbh->prepare($sql1);
    $get1->execute();

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `pictures` WHERE `auto_id` > $auto_id AND 
    `sold` = $soldvalue";
    $get2 = $dbh->prepare($sql2);
    $get2->execute();

    $attributes = 
    $auto =
    $pictures =
```

MY FINAL SOLUTION by @RichardA

```
// Get all the cars, join their attributes and pictures according to
// the `auto_id`
$query = "SELECT * FROM `auto`
INNER JOIN `attributes` ON `auto`.`auto_id` = `attributes`.`auto_id`
INNER JOIN `pictures` ON `auto`.`auto_id` = `pictures`.`auto_id`
WHERE `auto`.`soldvalue` = :soldvalue AND `auto`.`autoid` > :autoid";

// Prepare the query, binding parameters to prevent SQL injections
$getAutos = $dbh->prepare($query);

// Bind the autoid
$getAutos->bindParam(":autoid", $auto_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

// Bind the soldvalue
$getAutos->bindParam(":soldvalue", $soldvalue, PDO::PARAM_INT);

// Execute the query
$getAutos->execute();

// Fetch all the cars now, only getting an ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY
$autos = $getAutos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Loop through each car
foreach($autos as $auto)
{
    // Display the cars here
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I find your question a bit unclear.

Comment: @RichardA for a single car get all field info, store it in an array and access it... if you had a db for people and columns like age, dob, eyecolor then how could you query so you can `echo = $thispeopledata['dob'];`

Comment: Can't you then just get all the cars at once? Not sure if I'm understanding your idea.

Comment: @RichardA im doing this in a loop watch all my code im uploading

Comment: @RichardA it querys for each car, so if there is 30 cars, 30 sql will be performed for the appropiate car, the purpose is to get all info accesible in an array from the db for each car each time to display it, then again and again. i had it working with mysql but im switching to pdo

Comment: You would still be better off getting ALL the cars at once and then using a `foreach()` to iterate over them I'd say. On an unrelated note: You're open to sql injections like this.

Comment: @RichardA hmmm you just made me wonder of sql insertions, i thought pdo was my solution.. anyways. here is so you can better undestand me and thanks for helping me richard..

Comment: @RichardA i need to display each car as a form. so if there is 30 cars 30 forms need to be displayed, for managing purposes like changing price. now how am i supposed to display the right info as value for the text inputs? i need to query the data for that car, how am i going to do it them all at once? if im looping one by one

Comment: I'll try to post an answer to help you, hold on. On a note, a little database structure might help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch all the result by fetching them and store them in variable

```
$attributes = $get->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$auto       = $get1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$pictures   = $get2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

hence

```
$attribute[keyname / index name / column name] = value
$auto[keyname / index name / column name]      = value
$pictures[keyname / index name / column name] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single query, try something like this:

```
// Get all the cars, join their attributes and pictures according to
// the `auto_id`
$query = "SELECT * FROM `auto`
INNER JOIN `attributes` ON `auto`.`auto_id` = `attributes`.`auto_id`
INNER JOIN `pictures` ON `auto`.`auto_id` = `pictures`.`auto_id`
WHERE `auto`.`soldvalue` = :soldvalue AND `auto`.`autoid` > :autoid";

// Prepare the query, binding parameters to prevent SQL injections
$getAutos = $dbh->prepare($query);

// Bind the autoid
$getAutos->bindParam(":autoid", $auto_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

// Bind the soldvalue
$getAutos->bindParam(":soldvalue", $soldvalue, PDO::PARAM_INT);

// Execute the query
$getAutos->execute();

// Fetch all the cars now, only getting an ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY
$autos = $getAutos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Loop through each car
foreach($autos as $auto)
{
    // Display the cars here
}
```

Unlike your queries, these are actually [prepared](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and bound later. This prevents sql injection.

Check the comments on the code to see exactly what the meaning is behind everything.

Comment: how can i get specific info here? `$data['year'];` thanks alot this is really clean, and deff something new to me :)

Comment: $data[carid][datauwant];

Comment: @YoungStudent As `$autos` is an array, you can treat it as one, same goes for `$auto`. To get the info you want, you can simply use `$auto['auto_id']` or `$auto['soldvalue']`. If I were you though, I would do this inside your `foreach()` to know what's inside your array: `var_dump($auto); break;`. This limits the output to a single array being shown so you can be sure what kind of information you can use.

Comment: im getting `Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\cardealerwins\admin\tool\manage_vehicles.php on line 39` 39 = ` $getAutos->execute();`

Comment: Edit your question and post the error if you would, also the code you used.

Comment: @YoungStudent My bad on that one. The query has `:autoID` and I bound `:autoid` in the example. You can change either of the two. Those parameters are case-sensitive. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: still nothing `'Notice: Undefined variable: auto in C:\xampp\htdocs\cardealerwins\admin\tool\manage_vehicles.php on line 45'` while trying  `foreach($autos as $auto)
 {
  
   echo $auto['make'];
 }
 `

Comment: im not getting any more PDO errors tho, so i guess thats good :)

Comment: Maybe `$autos` is `false`. Use `var_dump($autos)` and check your query by executing it directly in PhpMyAdmin or whatever SQL program you use.

Comment: check my new code, before going to bed :) it appears its not looping, everything is right. pdo no errors, except proving that is looping for each auto, maybe the $auto_id is the problem on the bind param

Comment: @YoungStudent I'm not talking about PDO errors, I'm talking about SQL errors. If I were you I would let it sit for now and look at it with a fresh mind. If after everything it still fails, get 20 rep and then open a chat with me. I might be able to help better that way.

Comment: thanks alot, if you are looking to make some money, this application is one of the best to manage your cars as a cardealer, i have the support to sell this application 2 times a week for 2k each copy. you can deff hop in and sell it, plus my two sisters are going to make calls like crazy when its done, get me here and thanks alot facebook.com/jessraa1